# Saving data on external storage

Tags: android, file, directory, storage, external

I want to save some data in the user's external directory (ie. SD card), but there seems to be a weird problem. I'm using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` which returns "mnt/sdcard/" (which is fine). I want to create two folders on in this directory so I do:

```
File main = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/my_app/some_data");
if(!main.isDirectory())
    main.mkdirs();
```

Now I thought this would make the directory "mnt/sdcard/my_app/some_data", but after using a file manager to look at the SD card, it turns out that this folder is created at "mnt/sdcard/my_app/mnt/sdcard/my_app/some_data", which is quite bizarre. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following and see what you get...

```
String packageName =  this.getPackageName();
File myFilesDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator  + "Android" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + packageName + File.separator + "files");
myFilesDir.mkdirs();
```

It's exacly what I use to create a working directory on an SD card. For me it creates...

```
/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.mycompany.myApp/files
```

...where 'com.mycompany.myApp' is the actual package name of my app.

Comment: After a bit of modifications and adding your bit of code, I got it to work, thanks!

Comment: Hey can u add your answer here please

Comment: I think 'this' should be a `Context` eg: `context.getPackageName();`

Comment: @pjco : My answer was based on the assumption that the code will be run from an `Activity` or another Android class which extends `Context`. In that case using `this.getPackageName()` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Why would you assume File IO was being done on an Activity? I'd suggest adding that to avoid confusion.

Comment: is it always ok to assume that "/" is safe to be used instead of File.separator ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper : Good point. I would say "Yes" for all current (standard) versions of Android and all current devices (as far as I know) due to the file-system being based on a UNIX style. In saying that though it's possible somebody may port Android to a system which uses a different file-separator in which case using `File.separator` instead of `/` explicitly would make code "future proof".

Comment: so maybe it's best to do it use the File.separator , no?

Comment: Can you associate this folder with the app's app data so that when the user resets the app from the settings, all data in this folder is destroyed?